# Owl carousel - TypeError: this.$element.attr(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

On my wordpress site i use jQuery 1.12.4 together with owl carousel 2.2. When i load an carousel i get the following error:

```
TypeError: this.$element.attr(...) is undefined
```

The carousel is not working. jQuery is loadad in the header and owl carousel in the footer. I call owl carousel in a js file which is loadad after the owl carousel js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#services-slider").owlCarousel();
});
```

Comment: Could you please break this down into a [codepen](http://codepen.io)? That would be helpful.

Comment: It has someting to do with the version of owl carousel. I now use an old owl carousel version and it works.

Answer (score 6):

Just add any class to your #services-slider element. For examle

```
<div id="services-slider" class="owl-carousel">
  ....
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty poor that it only works on classes, surely there's not much effort involved to allow id's to work as well?

Answer (score 2):

Just minute ago have the same problem on Wordpress...

Look:

1. `id="services-slider"` - must be only ONE element with `id="services-slider"` on page
2. the element `id="services-slider"` must have `class="owl-carousel"`